# Perl script extracting web links using regular expression

Tags: regular-expression, perl, raspberry-pi

I am trying to write a script in perl and trying to extract web links using regular expression from a file  called file.txt(which has list of website). I am not able to print the links. Here is my code, thanks :

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl 
  use strict;
  use warnings;
   my @web;

   open my $input, '<', 'file.txt' or die $!;

 #loop through file
  while(my $row = <$input>){
   chomp $row;
    if($row =~ /http:(.+)/) {
       push @web, $1;
    }
  }  

 for my $w (@web){
   print "< $w\n";
 }
```

Comment: `http: (.+)` will match `http:` and then a literal space. How many of your links have a literal space like that?

Comment: I dont have space put it by mistake links looks like http://w1.weather.gov/obhistory

Answer (score 4):

[Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454), especially since with Perl it's easier to do it right.  For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::LinkExtor;

my ( @web, $fn, $p );

sub cb {
    my ( undef, %links ) = @_;
    push @web, values %links;
}

$p = HTML::LinkExtor->new( \&cb );
while ( $fn = shift ) {
    $p->parse_file($fn);
    $p->eof;
}

print "$_\n" for (@web);
```

Comment: Where does it take data from a file (file.txt)

Comment: `while ( $fn = shift )`

Comment: will it read line by line

Comment: how can I download HTML:: LinkExtor

Comment: @maria, from a shell prompt, do `cpan HTML::LinkExtor` to install the [module from CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTML::LinkExtor)

Comment: Also, it does not read a file line by line, using the `parse_file` method, it will analyze the entire file at once.

Comment: I think I will stick with regular expressions . Thanks though